# Приклеить div к низу экрана

Tags: html, css

Есть div с результатом подсчета калькулятора (#grid-15-15). Нужно этот div "приклеить" к низу экрана, чтобы он оставался там и прокручивался вместе со страницей, независимо от того, куда скроллит пользователь. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Калькулятор (сделан в Ucalc) можно посмотреть здесь: http://91.215.153.78/ucalc.html

Answer (score 0):

Для div
*CSS*

**position**: absolute

**bottom**: 0px (или 0%)

Тогда див приклеится к низу окна и всегда будет там!
В крайнем блоке сайта, тот, что находится в самом низу, нужно добавить:

**margin-bottom**: высота твоего калькулятора в пикселях, например 150px

Тогда крайний элемент не будет "перекрыт" калькулятором

Comment: если ставить position:absolute и bottom:0%, то нужный div становится просто поверх формы калькулятора, но к низу окна браузера не прижимается. Сейчас оставил такой вариант, посмотрите, пожалуйста, что я сделал не так. Крайнему элементу margin-bottom не прописывал, т.к. его на этой странице, по сути, нет. Весь калькулятор - это и есть единственный элемент.